# How can user input Location Viber chat bot?

Tags: chatbot, viber, viber-bot

I have created a chatbot for Viber using Botpress V12 framework and have implemented custom integration to integrate the bot to Viber(NodeJS). I want the user to enter a location during a flow of the bot but I don't how the user can input location to the Viber bot.

Is there a way in Viber to take input of location from the users?

I tried Location `ActionType` with parameter value `location-picker` But got this error

```
Response error { status: 3, status_message: 'keyboard is not valid. [instance value ("location-picker") not found
```

Comment: Hi! Looks like the keyboard structure is not valid. Can you show your kb structure?